# Python: Fixed Width Value In JSON Field

Tags: python, json

I'm in the process of learning Python and I'm currently messing around with the JSON file type. In order to keep the columns of my JSON file aligned, I need to be able to have a fixed width representation of an int/float. That is, if tournaments played is 5 but I want the width of the field to be 4 then I should get

```
{"name": "someName", "ranking": " C ", "tournamentsPlayed":     5}
```

instead of

```
{"name": "someName", "ranking": " C ", "tournamentsPlayed": 5}
```

However, when I try to format the width of this value before json.dump'ing into the file, it converts it to a string and I end up getting

```
{"name": "someName", "ranking": " C ", "tournamentsPlayed": "    5"}
```

I've tried to convert the formatted value back into an integer but it reverts back into being only as long as it needs to be as in the second code snippet. I know this isn't a JSON exclusive issue and it has to do with int representations all together, but is this even possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused about why you would need a JSON file to be aligned. JSON is a data interchange format, it is not for display.

Comment: I've never seen anyone try to align integers in JSON in this way.

Comment: JSON is also meant to be human-readable correct? I prefer to have every field aligned so that I can read it easier. I suppose if this isn't possible then I can create another text file and display the JSON data that way.

Comment: Everything is "human readable" given enough effort...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with the Python json module.

If you really want to achieve this, you'll need to manually output the JSON yourself - e.g.:

```
print '{"name": "%s", "ranking": "%s", "tournamentsPlayed": %5d}' % (
    name, ranking, tournamentsPlayed
)
```

You'll have to handle escaping yourself though (e.g. if a player name - the "name" variable above - has a double quote in it). Almost certainly not worth the hassle.

Comment: I already am outputting the JSON myself to pretty-print my info in a way that I prefer. What do you mean by "escaping" and a "play name"?

Comment: @RoboJacob5000 edited my reply to clarify player name. When you are outputting a format like JSON "escaping" means things you have to do to characters like " or , or {} to ensure they are treated as part of a string and are not interpreted as special JSON characters. The Python json module does that for you.

Comment: Okay yes. Than I have already handled escaping properly. Is using % the oldschool way of formatting or is it the proper choice here. I have tried using the str.format() but I will try your suggestion now.

Comment: It is strange. Your method seems to work due to the absence of quotes around the %5d. However, I can't find an equivalent using the .format() method. If I can't with further research then I will just stick with the oldschool approach. Thanks!